# SMPS feedback circuit with voltage regulation and current limiting

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, current-limiting, review

i’m self learning electronics for a few months now and i choose my first project to be a bench SMPS.
Since it is my first circuit design ever i really need some clarification.

My SMPS is 2-switch forward topology and i designed it to have:
adjustable output voltage 0-30V,
adjustable current limiting 0-10A

Please review my FB circuit:
Op amps are rail-to-rail, i computed values in the way that op amps are comparing 0-1V on one input(current sense, voltage) and 0-1V on second input(potentiometer adjusting)
[image: SMPS fb circuit with current limiting and voltage regulation]

Comment: Minor thought if you are going to mass produce this: you are converting your rail to rail opamp into open collector using external BJTs. It would be cheaper to use open collector opamps in the first place and just wire the outputs together and let your existing optocoupler resistor serve as pull-up. If it’s a one off, don’t bother.

Comment: @winny Took me a good hour to understand your comment, i finally get it, thanks for really good comment, you are right, with open collector op amps i wouldnt need those 2 BJTs at all.
I’ve already bought LMV358s so i will try it with BJTs.  Thanks for really good comment!

Answer (score 3):

Few comments:

Your feedback opamps have no compensation. You would end up trying to regulate out the ripple on your output and start oscillating like crazy. Check this link: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva662/slva662.pdf it is an article titled "Demystifying Type II and Type III compensators". I'd recommend a Type II compensator for this design (three extra components).

I have doubts about your current feedback circuit. Usually you would use a differential amplifier across your shunt, and then put that output into your error amplifier. Are you using this to regulate based on current or as a current limit?

I have not seen the BJT oring you're using before. I'd be worried about the two loops fighting each other. I usually use simple diodes to accomplish this, but I'm not sure how that'd work in your case.

Comment: 1. Compensation:
Somewhat makes sense, you are probably right about the oscillating output. I’ve somehow read the doc about op amp compensation, but i dont understand the theory behind it, i dont understand how the compensation works in my case, and how i should use it. Im using op amp as a comparator (not as an error/differential amplifier), just to decide if the output is high rail or low rail. I’m little bit lost.

Comment: 2. current limiting:  
2nd opamp with input from 0.1ohm shunt: I intend to use it just for current limiting. My thinking is that when output current exceeds  by potentiometer set current limit, FB is activated(op amp outputs high rail) and as a result output voltage is lowered -> which causes output current to go lower.

Comment: 3. BJT oring: 
op amps will output GND or high rail(4.22v), in combination with 10k resistors it causes BJTs to fully open or fully close. 2 BJTs connected the way i did should behave as a logic OR because just one open BJT is enough to pass current to optocoupler.

Comment: I’m new to all this, i’m not sure if my thinking is correct, please tell me if i’m wrong.

Comment: The compensation I mentioned is 3 components connected from the inverting terminal to the output of the opamp. A capacitor, and (in parallel) a capacitor and resistor in series. The capacitor with the resistor is usually an order of magnitude larger than the other cap. All these things do is get rid of high frequency noise and such so you can focus on the lower frequencies where all of the real transients are occurring. To calculate this involves taking the transfer function of your plant and then choosing your values to compensate that.

Comment: You can also use large capacitor values, 1u and 0.1u (resistor 50k-100k or so) to make the compensation stable easily, but it will be slow. Depends on how fast you need your supply to respond to transients. If you don't have a response analyzer or an oscilloscope, it will be hard to check these things anyway.

Comment: The problem with your current amp approach to this is you are thinking in an on-off mindset. In the analog world things are done gradually. Maybe post the other side of your feedback circuit? What is the opto connected to? Usually your "error" (the difference of your output and your set point) goes up higher the further off you are. You don't want your duty cycle going full every time you drop 1mV of of your set point. You would only want to increase it a little bit. If you were 4 or 5V off then it is a different story. That is essentially what compensation does.

Comment: @stiddly you are totally right about me having that on/off mindset, i will explain you why: i studied a lot of SMPS schemes and most of them use programmable voltage reference (for example TL431) which is connected to voltage divider with values set the way that there is 2.5V on REF pin, voltage reference has very steep transition on 2.5V which causes it to suddenly fully open even when there is 1mV over the ref voltage. This way there is full current through optocoupler or no current at all (on/off). So yes, i thought FB is only on or off. Am i wrong?  (Btw im using NCP1252a)

Comment: That seems to be the configuration the datasheet recommends. I had never seen that before, my mistake. Just because it isn't the way I do it, doesn't make it wrong. I was just sharing my thoughts.

Comment: More i know about SMPS more confused i am. It actually totally makes sense the way you described how FB works. When i check datasheet of TL494 which is used in big amount of SMPS (ATX), internally the chip has two op amps and their output also seems to be yes/no. I dont understand how can yes/no value meaningfully adjust duty cycle.

Comment: I design power supplies for work and I feel the same way.

There is a method of control called hysteretic control (or something similar, it's based on hysteresis) that has a set point above and below your desired voltage. It turns off when it hits the high limit, and on when it hits the lower limit. It can be incredibly precise.